# Is there a way to find the duplicate row id from "ER_DUP_ENTRY" error

Tags: mysql, node.js

As the title says , i want to minimize the number of quires by finding which row caused the duplicate error.

Comment: Show us all the error message, it is quite likely there is a clue in there

Comment: @RiggsFolly all i found so far is the sql server message that indicate there a confilict with a column for example "Error: ER_DUP_ENTRY: Duplicate entry 'value' for key 'name'" and i'm using mysql framework , the error handling  link  https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#error-handling